# The intouch triangle and excentral triangle

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $I_a$, $I_b$, and $I_c$ be the excenters of triangle $ABC$, and let $D$, $E$, $F$ be the intersection points of the incircle to segments $BC$, $AC$, and $AB$. Prove that the center of homothety taking $DEF$ to $I_aI_bI_c$ lies on line $OI$, where $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABC$ and $I$ is the incenter of $ABC$.

Comment: What was your attempt to prove this?

Comment: The original problem was to show that I_aD, I_bE, and I_cF and IO concur, and I proved the homothety that shows the first 3 lines concur. However i'm not sure how to show IO concurs.

Comment: A figure might help. I've got trouble with “… intersection points of the incenter to segments …” – what ist the intersection point of a point to a segment?

Comment: Hello, I've edited it to say incircle, not incenter

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4729484/427611.
Here is a solution from [Florida Atlantic University](https://www.math.fau.edu/): [The excentral and intouch triangles](http://math.fau.edu/yiu/AEG2013/AEG2013Chapter08.pdf)